# Android: Change alignment in the title bar

Tags: android, text, alignment, titlebar, android-titlebar

How do you change the horizontal alignment on the title bar?
Right now the default is set to the left side and I am trying to get it to be set to the right side.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the title bar or replace the title bar with your own View.

Comment: How do I remove the title bar? @CommonsWare

Comment: @Connor: Use `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` in the `<activity>` element of your manifest, or incorporate its settings into your own theme.